# Android: Highlight a street in MapView

Tags: android, android-mapview, gis

Using the MapView we need to apply a layer where a line appears over a road.

We can reverse Geo-code an address and Pin the location, but we can't get the set of Latitude/longitude points in order to draw a line along a street.

Is this possible someway?

Comment: this Q was 2 months ago , did you find a solution to this problem?